# Start-ScheduledTask queues task instead of running it

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks, remote-access

I'm having issues with creating scheduled task **remotely** on a computer.

This is my script:

```
$Action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "Robocopy" -Argument"""$downloadDirectory"" ""$fullDirectory"" /e /mt:32 /r:2 /w:2 /z /eta"
Register-ScheduledTask -User (Get-CimInstance –ClassName Win32_ComputerSystem | Select-Object -expand UserName) -Action $Action  -TaskName "ScriptUtilFileCopy" -Force 
Start-ScheduledTask -TaskName "ScriptUtilFileCopy"
```

The scheduled task will be run as the local user, not the account used to remote in with.

However, when I run `Start-ScheduledTask` **remotely**, the task is set to `Queued` with the code `0x0` in the Task Scheduler interface. But, if I run the task from Task Scheduled (ie. Right-Click --> Run), the task is run successfully.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with `remotely`? Do you connect to a remote system using `Enter-PSSession` or `Invoke-Command` to create the task?

Comment: @TobyU Hi, this is done by using `Invoke-Command`

Comment: Do you have the same Issue whilste running `Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName "ScriptUtilFileCopy"  | Start-ScheduledTask` after registering it? (maybe within a second `Invoke-Command`)

Comment: @TobyU Just tried it, still produces the same error. Task Scheduler says `Task Scheduler queued instance of task \ScriptUtilFileCopy.` Last run result also says `0x0`

Comment: Have you checked the event log for any errors?

Comment: I had this issue a while ago with just one server. This article describes the issue I had as well as the solution to fix it (at least in my case): https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/93uk01/fix_scheduled_task_get_queued_and_wont_run_server/

Comment: @TobyU I'm in a Windows 10 environment. This script is being run on client PC's so I'm not sure if that solution is applicable to me.

Comment: @montonero Event logs states that a new instance of the scheduled task was created and that it was launched.

Comment: You could try to monitor the task with a Process Monitor to see what is really happening when the task is run.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem and in my case, it was because of checked condition "Start the task only if the computer is on AC power". And laptop where I test this was really on battery.

After unchecking it, I was able to start it using Start-ScheduledTask.